# Unable to load class org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector error while establishing secured soap server using apache CXF

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

I am trying to publish secured SOAP server as a consuming endpoint at JBoss Fuse camel route. 
I have the following endpoint and Jetty-security description in my Blueprint configuration:

```
...
<cxf:cxfEndpoint
        xmlns:crm="http://www.bank.com/CRM"
        id="crmOutboundService"
        address="https://localhost:9001/cxf/CRMOutbound"
        serviceName="crm:CRMOutboundRq"
        endpointName="crm:ASBOCRMOutPort"
        wsdlURL="model/ASBOCRMOut/CRMOutboundRq.wsdl"
        serviceClass="com.bank.SAXSourceService">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD"/>
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>

<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
    <httpj:engine port="9001">
        <httpj:tlsServerParameters secureSocketProtocol="TLSv1">
            <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="password">
                <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password"
                file="/opt/esb/security/keystore.jks"/>
            </sec:keyManagers>
            <sec:trustManagers>
                <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password"
                              file="/opt/esb/security/truststore.jks"/>
            </sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_3DES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:exclude>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:exclude>
                <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
            </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
            <sec:clientAuthentication want="true" required="true"/>
        </httpj:tlsServerParameters>
    </httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>
...
```

Everything as in manual from here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/pdf/apache_cxf_security_guide/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.2-Apache_CXF_Security_Guide-en-US.pdf

I have (among others) the following dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When application bundle is deployed into JBoss Fuse the following exception comes:

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to load class org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector from recipe MapRecipe[name='#recipe-11850']"
```

The questions are: why does such an error take place and what is the right way to establish secured SOAP server in JBoss Fuse?

Answer (score 0):

We have ended up with adding the following directive into Blueprint descriptor:

```
<bean id="server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server"/>
```

The error has gone, and the application is working correctly, but we do not actually understand why, because there are no any references to the new bean. We are trying to figure out, if this directive starts new instance of Jetty server.